# How to print alternate elements in string using python

Tags: python, string

- I have one string 'abcdef'
- Need to print element like first element, last element, second element, second last element
- Expected out is `afbecd`
- Another output for `abcde` Expected is `aebdc`
- Can we do it in without creating a extra list

pseudo code:

```
str1 = 'abcdef'
i= 0
j = 1
new_str = ''
while (i < len(str1) && j > len(str1) and i!=j):
   new_str = str1[i] + str1[j]
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Can you show some real code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your approach you can do:

```
str1 = 'abcdef'
i= 0
j = len(str1) - 1
new_str = ''
while (j>i):
   new_str += str1[i] + str1[j]
   i+=1
   j-=1

if len(str1) % 2 != 0:
    new_str += str1[j]
print(new_str)
```

Output:

```
afbecd
```

Comment: Could also do `if j == i:` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Without any spurious memory usage, you can use some lazy iterators/generators with `reversed` and `zip`

```
def interleave(s):
    gen = (c for pair in zip(s, reversed(s)) for c in pair)
    return "".join(next(gen) for _ in s)

>>> interleave("abcdef")
'afbecd'
>>> interleave("abcde")
'aebdc'
```

You can introduce more utils to shorten the code even more:

```
from itertools import chain  

def interleave(s):
    gen = chain.from_iterable(zip(s, reversed(s)))
    return "".join(next(gen) for _ in s)
```

Comment: seems like the ideal solution, I just went with the op approach.

Comment: Both are valid. For beginners, it is always helpful to understand the "manual" loopy approach before heaving the kitchen sink of built-ins and library functions at a simple problem.

Comment: Next gen is already old, the [next](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETv@Yqll2ZBvHgRwS8RkZpuNJJmwyYt9uvjai/OYWGY2Xl5rU9Oh2OW1rzwBKGSVOZYIEyZpYJbXSRjRvIQkoaRhoVswZMB1YMSnLeOvXx/NdmB0EJSaFRzxV9PqM6SoOv2Lw7JJnrX7egAIngWuOk@FDQmi4LsH6wf7k75PWJrHw) next gen is all the hype now :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode :-) That's a creative approach. And a seriously elegant one to boost. You should go all the way tho with the abstraction layers and generators: `gen = cycle(f(s) for f in (iter, reversed))`

Comment: If only Python 3 still had `apply`, then I think `cycle(map(apply, (iter, reversed), repeat(s)))` would work.

Comment: Ha, I was wondering about such a util. Like `map` but applying multiple functions to the same argument instead of vice versa.

Comment: An reverse `map`.... say hello to [pam](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEITvfYqll2alePEigs8iNd3USJqETVrs08f8IDiHXRh25xt/xJezl6vnlBS7FXQkjs6ZAHr1jiPIQxrqupkU@GkVarMyjHCaeAl46yBLOYZig7Z1h2YXHZrMXE3RPlqQtpliaNpJ/EIWsnBvMFE4ohQZgWknDjTjCAGxXjLFjS30/fnttBWWPrGNHIFY2zxKlQLznFHiDzdMT5kbDIgpfQE) :-)

Comment: If that's not standard library stuff and deserving of heavy C-optimization, I don't know what is :D

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two possibilities based on string length here but they really only differ in how you handle the middle character. Therefore, an input of `abcdefg` should give you an output of `agbfced` whereas the output for `abcdef` would be `afbecd`.

Given the above, I think this should work:

```
def zip_str(input_str):
    width = len(input_str)
    half_width = int(width / 2)
    new_str = ""
    for i in range(0, half_width):
        new_str += input_str[i] + input_str[-1 - i]
    return new_str if width % 2 == 0 else new_str + input_str[half_width]
```

Answer (score 0):

A not particularly efficient but simple and imho fun way is to keep reversing the remaining string ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctBDkAwEEDR/ZxidlXsbETiMNRImzTVzBRx@lJs/8uPV7Jb6PrIOQuOqKbZLLQqACbZfSpJwWmdJ5QBELGWFo2d@BGmg1hoqUQX@Y9mfB0gsgup@qrO@QY)):

```
s = 'abcdef'

result = ''
while s:
   *s, char = reversed(s)
   result += char

print(result)
```

Or, since you actually say you want to *print* ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoAgDADQu1@x2zS8dYnAjzFdKITJJkVfv@r8Xn9GOdu8dFYVCIBxS5l2NOYu9SCQ1QDAJB5SifwFpotYKFtxv3SubdjfPFDLAdGpvg)):

```
s = 'abcdef'

while s:
   *s, char = reversed(s)
   print(char, end='')
```